# Insert a array in a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I have two arrays called one and two. `one` contains string values and `two` int values.
I'm trying:

```
var messageObject = { 'One': one,
                       'Two': two};
var serializedJSON = JSON.stringify(messageObject);
var json = JSON.parse(serializedJSON);
alert(json.One);
```

I'm getting "Undefined", though the array is populated.
They are receiving data from a database, like this:

```
db.transaction(function(transaction) {
    transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM aluno', [], function(transaction, results) {
        len = results.rows.length, i;
        for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
            one[i] = results.rows.item(i).fieldOne;
            two[i] = results.rows.item(i).fieldTwo;
        }            
    }, null);
});
```

See the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/U4C6r/2/

Comment: Please post the two arrays.

Comment: are you sure you defined `one` and `two` before defining `messageObject` ?

Comment: [cannot reproduce](http://jsbin.com/nuvusuke/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: Seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/U4C6r/

Comment: See the update, please. Is there any problem receiving data from database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT to updated:
put breakpoint as you read the values from webSQL and check the structure of object you get within loop inspect this obj results.rows.item(i)

Also change your script to this. I am assuming you have global var one = []; and var two = []; declared.

```
var dynamicArrayContainer = { one : [], 
two : []};
db.transaction(function(transaction) {
transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM table', [], function(transaction, results) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
        dynamicArrayContainer .one.push(results.rows.item(i).fieldOne);
        dynamicArrayContainer .two.push( results.rows.item(i).fieldTwo);
    }            
}, null);
});
```

Try this, put your values directly, as debug exercise

```
var serializedJSON = JSON.stringify(dynamicArrayContainer);
var json = JSON.parse(serializedJSON);
alert(json.one);
```

Comment: See the update, please. Is there any problem receiving data from database?

Comment: I try, it worked.
But I need creating the array dinamically.
Would you try it, please?

Comment: I didn't know exists that "push" method. Thank for that.
But still doesn't work out. Can you have a look at the code?
http://jsfiddle.net/U4C6r/10/

Comment: I tried it in my real code. It worked properly.
The JSFiddle my has some problem with databases, I don't know.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Edited Answer:

The problem seems to be with the DB-Query-Code. Either the query or the callback get never executed, see: http://jsfiddle.net/U4C6r/11/

---

Original Answer:

```
var messageObject = { 
  'One': one,
  'Two': two
};
```

If you define your keys as strings, you should access them as such:

```
console.log(json['One']);
```

If you'd like to have them as properties on the object, you should do:

```
var messageObject = { 
  One: one,
  Two: two
};
```

Then you could access the data in a chaining fashion, like you want to:

```
console.log(json.One);
```

You should also see the difference here and in your IDE 
by the specific Syntax-Highlighting - see it? :)

Comment: Okay, so this wasn't the problem here - sorry.

It seems your DB-Execution-Callback is never executed, see: http://jsfiddle.net/U4C6r/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var messageObject = { One: 'one',
                       Two: 'two'};
var serializedJSON = JSON.stringify(messageObject);
var json = JSON.parse(serializedJSON);
alert(json.One);
```

Good luck
:)

**Update: Enquirer edited the query after this reply was posted. This reply pertains to the original query (ie the first part of the current query)**

Comment: See the update, please.
Is there any problem receiving data from database?

Comment: Why was this answer marked down?
At the time I posted, it corresponded to the (unedited) query.
Query was edited afterwards.
The mark-down process seems rather supercilious in addition to discouraging further participation.

Comment: Actually, I use to mark all up, just for thanking the response.

Comment: Thank you LIUFA & MCGBra ...TBH, I am becoming increasing hesitant in replying. I know it is not your fault :)